# jquery conflict in custom wordpress plugin

Tags: wordpress, plugins

using jquery in my custom WordPress plugin on init I get the following error `Type Error: $.effects.effect is undefined`. Another problem: live event is getting ignored and I'm getting `jQuery(...).live is not a function`. I have been trying to load in my plugin the newest Jquery but even like that the problem persist

```
public function init()
    {
        wp_deregister_script('jquery');
        wp_register_script('jquery', ("http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.9.1.js"), false, '');
        wp_enqueue_script('jquery-ui-js', 'http://code.jquery.com/ui/1.10.1/jquery-ui.js');
        wp_enqueue_script('jquery');
        wp_enqueue_script( 'konfigurator_ajax', plugin_dir_url( __FILE__ ) . 'config.js', array( 'jquery' ) );
        wp_localize_script( 'konfigurator_ajax', 'Konfigurator', array(
                'ajaxurl' => admin_url( 'admin-ajax.php') ,
                'nonce' => wp_create_nonce( 'konfigurator_ajax-nonce' )
        ) );
```

Comment: Hey fefe, are you meant to be enqueuing your jquery-ui-script before your jquery script?

Comment: Also, isn't deregistering jquery a bad idea - it might stop other plugins or themes working while your plugin is active.

Comment: I'm trying to use the latest jquery, maybe there is another workaround to load the latest jquery in plugin

Answer (score 0):

I dont see your `config.js` but I think it uses jQuery UI effect. You need to separate register and enqueue for right `wp_enqueue_script` work. Also your code is non-WP standart, im suggest you to use this code (right-installed WordPress 3.5+):

```
public function init() {
   wp_register_script('konfigurator_ajax', plugin_dir_url(__FILE__) . 'config.js', array( 'jquery', 'jquery-ui-core', 'jquery-effects-core' ));
   wp_localize_script( 'konfigurator_ajax', 'Konfigurator', array(
       'ajaxurl' => admin_url( 'admin-ajax.php') ,
       'nonce' => wp_create_nonce( 'konfigurator_ajax-nonce' )
   ));
}
add_action('admin_init', 'init'); //or if OOP add_action('admin_init', array(&$this, 'init'));

public function print_scripts() {
    wp_enqueue_script('jquery-ui-core');
    wp_enqueue_script('jquery-effects-core');
    wp_enqueue_script('konfigurator_ajax');
}
add_action('admin_print_scripts', 'print_scripts'); //or if OOP add_action('admin_print_scripts', array(&$this, 'print_scripts'));
```